# Localization with xml without compilation?

Tags: c#, localization

I am looking for the best way to implement a winform with different languages, but i don't want to use the resources files of Visual Studio because you always have to recompile.

I have found the following solution to use XML files without compilation:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/xml_localization.aspx

I find it is OK, users can edit the xml and in the future they could provide my application with translations.

Do you know a better way for this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining your own XML-based internalization system you could go the standard way by using one such as [Translation Memory eXchange](http://www.lisa.org/Translation-Memory-e.34.0.html) format.

Comment: Could you provide some class or tool to implement this?

Comment: We implemented our own language manager libraries to implement runtime language switch for our application. We develop in Java but the same should apply to your environment.

I don't currently know about a framework that uses TMX for C# applications, but developing a new one shouldn't be so hard.